# $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin^3x}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits

How can I show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin^3x}{x^2+y^2}=0 \qquad\quad ?$$
I have already tried it when $x=0$, $y=0$ and $y=mx$. Those lines all yield $0$. I don't know if I can use L'Hôpital's rule because I don't know what I would differentiate with respect to.

Comment: $|\sin x|\le |x|$.

Comment: I've tried that - I get $L\leq \left| \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right|$ where $L$ is the limit.

Comment: Just FYI, you cannot you L'Hospital's rule for limits of multiple variables, unless one of the variables is a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use @GEdgar's hint:
$$ 0 \leq \left|\frac{\sin^3{x}}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq \frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2} $$

Now, let's look at the limit from a polar perspective:
$$ \frac{r^3\left|\cos^3{\theta}\right|}{r^2} = r\left|\cos^3{\theta}\right| \leq r$$

This gives us
$$ 0 \leq \left|\frac{\sin^3{x}}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq r $$

Since $(x,y)\to0$ corresponds to $r\to0$, we can use squeeze theorem to evaluate the limit as 0.

Comment: $y$ wasn't ever necessary, not even polar coordinates :)  $$ 0 \leq \left|\frac{\sin^3{x}}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq \frac{|x|^3}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{|x|^3}{x^2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\rho \cos \phi$ and $y=\rho \sin \phi$.  The limit becomes

$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{\sin^3(\rho \cos \phi)}{\rho^2}$$

Can you use L'Hospital's Rule on this limit now?

Comment: Yes. It is form 0/0, which gives $\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{3\sin^2(\rho\cos\phi)\cdot\cos\phi}{2\rho}\overset{\text{L'H}}{\underset{\frac00}{=}}\lim_{\rho \to 0}\frac{6\sin(\rho\cos\phi)\cdot\cos^2\phi}{2}=0$